# Order of JSON node changes while making POST request Swift

Tags: json, swift, authorize.net

I was trying to post the following jSON body
request JSON :

```
let parameters =  [
        "createTransactionRequest": [
            "merchantAuthentication": [
                "name": "xxxxxxxx",
                "transactionKey": "xxxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "refId": "123456",
            "transactionRequest": [
                "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
                "amount": "5",
                "payment": [
                    "opaqueData": [
                        "dataDescriptor": desc!,
                        "dataValue": tocken!
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

When I am trying to print(parameters) the order of node changes it looks like

```
["createTransactionRequest":

 ["refId": "123456", 
"transactionRequest":

 ["payment":  ["opaqueData": ["dataDescriptor": "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT", "dataValue": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="]],

 "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",

 "amount": "5"],

 "merchantAuthentication": ["name": "xxxxxxx", "transactionKey": 

"6gvE46G5seZt563w"]
]
]
```

I am getting response like

```
{ messages =     {
        message =         (
                        {
                code = E00003;
                text = "The element 'createTransactionRequest' in namespace

 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 

'refId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of

 possible elements expected: 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 

'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.";
            }
        );
        resultCode = Error;
    };
}
```

This is really annoying. anyones help will be highly grateful.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the order is. And dictionaries have no order so there's nothing you can do anyway.

Comment: thanks for reply . why am getting a response like " has invalid child element 

'refId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of

 possible elements expected: 'merchantAuthentication'"

Comment: This indicated that the structure of your dictionary does not match what the server expects.

Comment: this is desired json   {
    "createTransactionRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID",
            "transactionKey": "YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY"
        },
        "refId": "123456",
        "transactionRequest": {
            "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
            "amount": "5",
            "payment": {
                "opaqueData": {
                    "dataDescriptor": "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT",
                    "dataValue": "PAYMENT_NONCE_GOES_HERE"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: is there any error in structure of dictionary that I have created above

Comment: If the error message can be trusted, your sample JSON also violates the the schema, in that it too has `refId` a child property of `createTransactionRequest`. Apparently only `merchantAuthentication` is valid. A cursory glance at https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your data structure as follow:

```
struct Transaction: Codable {
    let createTransactionRequest: CreateTransactionRequest
}
struct CreateTransactionRequest: Codable {
    let merchantAuthentication: MerchantAuthentication
    let refId: String
    let transactionRequest: TransactionRequest
}
struct MerchantAuthentication: Codable {
    let name: String
    let transactionKey: String
}
struct TransactionRequest: Codable {
    let transactionType: String
    let amount: String
    let payment: Payment
}
struct Payment: Codable {
    let opaqueData: OpaqueData
}
struct OpaqueData: Codable {
    let dataDescriptor: String
    let dataValue: String
}
```

---

Testing

```
let json = """
    { "createTransactionRequest":
        { "merchantAuthentication":
            { "name": "YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID",
               "transactionKey": "YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY"
             },
          "refId": "123456",
          "transactionRequest":
               { "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
                 "amount": "5",
                 "payment":
                   { "opaqueData":
                       { "dataDescriptor": "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT",
                         "dataValue": "PAYMENT_NONCE_GOES_HERE"
                        }
                    }
                }

             }

          }
"""
let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)
do {
    let transaction = try JSONDecoder().decode(Transaction.self, from: jsonData)
    print(transaction)
    // encoding
    let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(transaction)
    print(String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

> {"createTransactionRequest":{"merchantAuthentication":{"name":"YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID","transactionKey":"YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY"},"refId":"123456","transactionRequest":{"transactionType":"authCaptureTransaction","amount":"5","payment":{"opaqueData":{"dataValue":"PAYMENT_NONCE_GOES_HERE","dataDescriptor":"COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT"}}}}}

Comment: how can I use json {} in swift. can I replace it with []

Comment: What do you mean? You shouldn't create your json string manually.

Comment: sorry, idont understand this let json = """{ "createTransactionRequest":
        { "merchantAuthentication":{ "name": "YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID",
               "transactionKey": "YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY"},
          "refId": "123456",
          "transactionRequest":
               { "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
                 "amount": "5",
                 "payment":
                   { "opaqueData":
                       { "dataDescriptor": "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT",
                         "dataValue": "PAYMENT_NONCE_GOES_HERE"
                        }} }  }  }

Comment: I want insert respective values to nodes, meant payment credentials ,amount etc

Comment: thanks for ur valuable information.see struct OpaqueData: Codable {
    let dataDescriptor: String
    let dataValue: String
} when I am printing it properties inside opaqData prints  like dataValue comes first, dataDescriptor comes second. how can I get in given order

Comment: You can make the struct conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement the description property as you would like it to print `var description: String { return "Property1: \(property1) - Property2: \(property2)" }` and so on. You can do it for all your structs